# how to databind textbox inside WPF datagrid to a property in viewmodel?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

How to bind textbox inside WPF Data grid to a property in view model? I am using MVVM pattern.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Channels}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Display Name">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding DisplayName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200"/>                        
</DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

DisplayName is a property as defined below:

```
private string displayName;
        public string DisplayName
        {
            get { return displayName; }
            set
            {
                if (displayName != value)
                {                    displayName = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => DisplayName);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: -1 It's a bad question, please try to google your issue.

Comment: Agree with dev. Post some code which you have tried and facing issue in it.

Answer (score 3):

In case you simply want to bind text, i would suggest to use `DataGridTextColumn` instead of `DataGridTemplateColumn`. No need to recreate column which already exists.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Channels}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          ColumnWidth="*" CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Display Name"
                            Width="200"
                            Binding="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I want a textbox column inside datagrid

Comment: @user2951819 there is a TexBox inside the CellEditingTemplate by default

Comment: @user2951819 - Agree with WiiMaxx but i have one question why you want to bind to property in ViewModel. It should be in model class i.e. `Channel` class (assuming Channels is a collection of objects of Channel class).

Comment: But in case you only want `TextBox` for both CellTemplate and CellEditingTemplate, your code will work fine but it will search for property in Channel class and not in ViewModel class.

Comment: @RohitVats it could be an ViewModel with a Collection of ViewModels

Comment: Channels should be collection of ViewModels then and it will work.